# Duplicate code in setOnClickListener method - android - java

Tags: java, android

I just wanted to know, if there is a better way to use `setOnClickListener` for several buttons and reduce redundant code.

Here is my code:

```
private void addListenerOnColorButtons() {
        redButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRed);
        redButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (!red) {
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Red is selected!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    red = true;
                } else {
                    red = false;
                }
            }
        });
        blueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBlue);
        blueButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (!blue) {
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Blue is selected!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    blue = true;
                } else {
                    blue = false;
                }
            }
        });
        greenButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGreen);
        greenButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (!green) {
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Green is selected!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    green = true;
                } else {
                    green = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to implement your activity the

> OnClickListener

and adjust your code with the following structure :

```
    private void attachListenersOnColorButtons() {
    redButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRed);
    redButton.setTag("RedButton"); // this tag will be used as identifier in onClick method
    redButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    blueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBlue);
    blueButton.setTag("BlueButton");
    blueButton.setOnClickListener(this);


    greenButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGreen);
    greenButton.setTag("GreenButton");
    greenButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    if(v.getTag().equals("RedButton")){
        // actions when red button is pressed
    }else if(v.getTag().equals("BlueButton")){
        // corresponding actions for blue button
    }else if(v.getTag().equals("GreenButton"){
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your class implement onClickListener, override the OnClickListener() method in the class.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I already implemented `onClickListener` and used `setOnClickListener(this)` for a different button, can I use it multiple times?

Comment: Sure, that's the point. You implement onClickListener in your class, and add button.setOnClickListener(this) to every button you want to handle clicks on.

Comment: The question was related to the ways of avoiding duplicate code in the setOnClickListener method. So in this case, I think this is the point.

Comment: My point is clearer once you start to do it. There are two answers along these lines of a shared OnClickListener. If they were complete examples, you'd see just as much duplication.

Comment: But what if you want to do pretty much the same thing on each view's onClick and 1 or 2 lines of code differ?

Comment: Where would you put that code? remember, you're suggesting reusing a click handler that they are already using for other buttons, so can't put before and after the switch.

Comment: It would work in Jaguars example. So yes they can share, but wouldn't be the nicest to share with other buttons that are doing other things.

Answer (score 1):

You can do in this way :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
private Button redButton;
private Button greenButton;

private int clickedButtonTag;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.avticity_compte);

    redButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.redButton);
    greenButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.greenButton);

    redButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    greenButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{

    switch (view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.redButton:
        case R.id.greenButton:
            clickedButtonTag = Integer.parseInt((String) view.getTag());

        break;

        default:
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: OK, but as soon as they fill in the todos, there'll be just as much duplicate code.

Comment: Yes you are right. You should use "tag". In your XML code, add this line android:tag="0" for every button. And retreive the correspondant tag for each button. You don't have to duplicate code using this way (I edited my response)

Comment: Not a bad idea that, they could use an array of booleans rather than 3 named booleans. Then the tag is the index to it.

Comment: There is multiple ways, and you have to choose one ^^

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way.

In your layout file set clickable property of all the buttons and give same method name in all the buttons:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonBlue"
    ...
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="onClick"/>
   ...
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonGreen"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="onClick"/>
```

In your activity create a method with name onClick like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
     switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.buttonBlue:
          // Blue button code
         break;
        case R.id.buttonGreen:
         // Green button code
          break;
        case R.id.buttonRed:
         // Red button code
          break;
        default:
      }
}
```

Comment: This approach is okay only if you don't have to pass anything in the method you add to "android:onClick". If you want to pass the method's name from xml, you are only allowed to pass a single parameter and this is a View object.

Comment: @Mike Do you have need to pass parameters to it?

Comment: Yes, by default you must pass a single View object as a parameter to your method. So your method should look like public void myClickMethodForXml(View v) {}

Comment: As soon as they fill in the blanks, there'll be just as much duplicate code.

Comment: @Mike If you want to reduce your code and want to define clickable property in layout, you will have to pass view object.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want 3 toggle buttons, then you don't need the booleans and your users will have some visual feedback: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html.

The main way to avoid duplicate code is to extract the common code in to functions. Determine the differences and pass them in to these functions as parameters. The below demonstrates this even if you choose to stay with `Button`.

Note I only have to have three clicked functions because of the toast, so if that's debug, it can all be one:

XML:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onRedToggleClicked"/>
<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onGreenToggleClicked"/>
<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onBlueToggleClicked"/>
```

Activity:

```
public void onRedToggleClicked(View view) {
    colourToggleChanged((ToggleButton) view), "Red");
}

public void onGreenToggleClicked(View view) {
     colourToggleChanged((ToggleButton) view), "Blue");
}

public void onRedToggleClicked(View view) {
     colourToggleChanged((ToggleButton) view), "Green");
}

private void colourToggleChanged(ToggleButton toggle, String colourName) {
    // Is the toggle on?
    boolean on = toggle.isChecked();
    if (on)
      Toast.makeText(this, colourName + " is selected!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="red" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:text="blue" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:text="green" />
```

Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
public Button redButton,blueButton,greenButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    redButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    blueButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    greenButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

    redButton.setOnClickListener(this);blueButton.setOnClickListener(this);greenButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0)
{
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ((Button)arg0).getText()+" is selected", 0).show();
}
```

}